# How to do a HTML5 Canvas scale animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas, scale

I'm working on a canvas white board tool. Now I'm at the point where I work on the Zoom In and Zoom Out feature.

This is working fine so far, but now I like to make a smooth animation for the scaling.
But it seems it is to fast, that I see no effect. I click on the + or - button and boom it's scaled.

```
let scaleAmount = 1.00;

function scaleUpdate()
{
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.scale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount)   
    
    scaleSize.innerText = parseInt(parseFloat(scaleAmount.toFixed(2))*100)+"%";

    stageUpdate();  
   
}

function scale(direction)
{
    let scaleSize = document.getElementById("scaleSize");
    
    if(direction=="zoomIn")
    { 
        for(let i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            scaleAmount += 0.01;
            scaleAmount = parseFloat(scaleAmount.toFixed(2));
            dx += scaleAmount;
            dy += scaleAmount;   
            
            scaleUpdate();
        }
    }
    if(direction=="zoomOut")
    {
        for(let i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            scaleAmount -=0.01;
            scaleAmount = parseFloat(scaleAmount.toFixed(2));
            dx -= scaleAmount;
            dy -= scaleAmount;
            scaleUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

**dx** and **dy** are screen offsets.

Could someone help me to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update visual properties like the scale inside a for-loop, it literally happens at all once - not really of couse but way faster than the eye. The screen does not get updated with each iteration of your for-loop. It's more like before calling the `scale()` function and after it' finished (also not really but you get the idea).

To make those changes visible you need to do 'em over time. For example at start time 1.0 set the scale to 1, at 1.1 set it to 1.01, at 1.2 set it to 1.02 and so on until reaching your target scale. This can be done by using either the `setInterval()` or `requestAnimationFrame()` function. setInterval takes two arguments, the function to call and the time when to call this function in milliseconds. requestAnimationFrame tries to call the supplied function at the refreshrate of your display - so if it`s a 60hz display it will be called close to 60 times a second.

If we modify your example to take advantage of the requestAnimationFrame function:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("scaleUp").onclick = () => {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationID);
  scale("zoomIn");
}
document.getElementById("scaleDown").onclick = () => {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationID);
  scale("zoomOut");
}

let scaleAmount = 1.0;
let animationID;

function scale(direction) {
  let animationReady = false;
  let targetScale;
  if (direction == "zoomIn") {
    scaleAmount += 0.01;
    targetScale = 2;
    animationReady = scaleAmount >= targetScale;
  }
  if (direction == "zoomOut") {
    scaleAmount -= 0.01;
    targetScale = 1;
    animationReady = scaleAmount <= targetScale;
  }

  if (animationReady) {
    scaleAmount = targetScale;
  } else {
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      scale(direction);
    });
  }
  stageUpdate();
}

function stageUpdate() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.scale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 45, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

stageUpdate();
```

```html
<button id="scaleUp" type="button">Scale +</button><button id="scaleDown" type="button">Scale -</button><br><canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: if I add ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2) the upper left corner of the canvas moves to the middle of the screen, but the scaled objects are still moving from top left to bottom right on zoomIn. 
I have a grid in the background. this is only visible in the lower right corner then.

Answer (score 0):

@obscure Your answer was really helpful, thanks.

My final code looks like this:

```
let scaleAmount = 1.00;
let scaleAnimation;
let animationReady = false;
let scalePercent =  parseInt(scaleSize.innerText.replace("%",""));
function scaleUpdate()
{
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.scale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount)   
    
    scaleSize.innerText = parseInt(parseFloat(scaleAmount.toFixed(1))*100)+"%";

    stageUpdate();  
   
}

function scale(direction)
{
    
    
    let targetScale ;

    if(direction=="zoomIn")
    { 
            targetScale = scalePercent / 100 + 0.1;
            
            scaleAmount += 0.01;
        
            animationReady = scaleAmount > targetScale;
            targetScale= parseFloat(targetScale.toFixed(3));
            scaleAmount = parseFloat(scaleAmount.toFixed(3));
            dx += scaleAmount;
            dy += scaleAmount;   
    }
    if(direction=="zoomOut")
    {
            targetScale = scalePercent / 100 - 0.1;

            scaleAmount -= 0.01;
           
            animationReady = scaleAmount < targetScale;
            targetScale= parseFloat(targetScale.toFixed(3));
            scaleAmount = parseFloat(scaleAmount.toFixed(3));
            dx -= scaleAmount;
            dy -= scaleAmount;
    }
 
    if (animationReady) {
        scaleAmount = targetScale;
        scalePercent =  parseInt(scaleSize.innerText.replace("%",""));
    } else {
        scaleAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            scaleUpdate();
            scale(direction);
         });
    }
}
```